# jQuery getting a modified URL in Laravel 5.3

Tags: jquery, laravel-5.3

I am trying to populate dynamic dropdown menus in Laravel using jQuery. I have a dropdown menu with list of counties and another empty dropdown that will be filled with constituencies from the selected county in the counties dropdown. The problem I am facing is a wrong URL being returned by the AJAX call. This is part of my javascript:

```
var url = 'filters/constituencies/' + countyID;
if (countyID) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data)
```

I am on localhost using XAMPP. This is what I am getting in the console:

> jquery.js:10254 GET http://localhost/myapp/public/filters/filters/constituencies/5 404 (Not Found)

I notice that the URL (`http://localhost/myapp/public/filters/constituencies/5`) has been modified to `http://localhost/myapp/public/filters/filters/constituencies/5` making it unavailable. This is my route:

```
Route::get('filters/constituencies/{countyID}', ['as'=>'reportFilterConst', 'uses'=>'ReportFiltersController@filterConstituencies']);
```

I when I try to access the URL manually in the browser it works just fine. What is causing part of the url get duplicated:
`http://localhost/myapp/public/**filters/filters**/constituencies/5`

I have tried to use route name instead of a URL but this has the same problem. Please assist me.

Comment: Are you sure you're not just using the wrong URL in the AJAX request depending on the page you're in, as the URL you're using is relative? Try using a URL relative to the root URL of the site, eg: `url: '/myapp/public/filters/filters/constituencies/' + countyID;`

Comment: Thank you, but this returns internal server error.